# How to create a template with CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to create a template like this one:

[image: Template]

But im not sure if I have to created with css, bootstrap or both.

[This is what I have](https://jsfiddle.net/uzdjhfxx/)

HTML:

```
<div class="square">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img src="../Images/logo.png" class="text-left" style="width:120px;"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 text-center">
            <h4>Alert PLC</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 text-center">
            <h4>No. Alert: 44445543</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <hr class="line" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
background-color: #aeaeae;
}   
.square {
padding-top: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.line {
height: 4px;
color: #000000;
border-radius: 2px;
background-color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: You will need to change your markup https://jsfiddle.net/uzdjhfxx/1/

Comment: FYI Francisco, media queries go in the CSS box, not the JS box.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [JSfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DhwaniSanghvi/uzdjhfxx/3/)
Hope it will help you.I made several changes in html.

### HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="square">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/retro-retro-hipster-bicycle-design_23-2147491723.jpg" class="pull-left" style="width:120px;"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <h4>Alert PLC</h4>
            </div>
             <hr class="line" />
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                <h4>No. Alert: 44445543</h4>
            </div>



        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is a problem with the <hr /> must be under the last div, and next to the image. I update your code, but the <hr /> is to far from the image and I want it more close. https://jsfiddle.net/uzdjhfxx/4/